# CodeIgniter - my insert query does not work - returning error without error number

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, oracle11g

I am using CodeIgniter to insert a new record to an Oracle table in php. THe code is on the below:

```
public function insert_street_file( $insdata = null )
    {
        if ($insdata == null)
        {
            // return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $insdata = array(
            'NAME'=>"Eray",
            'SURNAME'=>"BAlk",
            'CITY'=>"HALIFAX",
            'PROVINCE'=>"NS",
            'LSTNOLO'=>1,
            'LSTNOHI'=>2,
            'RSTNOLO'=>3,
            'RSTNOHI'=>4,
            'POSTCODE'=>"b3h1s8",
            'POSTDIR'=>"1s8",
            'PREDIR'=>"b3h",
            'STR_CODE'=>30002
        );

$results =$this->oracle_db->insert("$this->street_file_table_name", $insdata);
return $results;
```

And i am getting the error below:

```
Error Number: 

INSERT
INTO People
     ("NAME", "SURNAME", CITY", "PROVINCE", "LSTNOLO", "LSTNOHI",
      "RSTNOLO", "RSTNOHI", "POSTCODE", "POSTDIR", "PREDIR", "STR_CODE")
 VALUES ('Eray', 'Balk', 'Halifax', 'NS', 1, 2,
     3, 4, 'b3h1s8', '1s8', 'b3h', 30002)

Filename: C:\inetpub\ci-2-1-3-system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

- There is no error number specified, so I don't know what exactly the problem is.
- DB connection is provided, any select query works well.
- $this->street_file_table_name value is correct
- column names are also in capital letters in the Oracle db. All column names and table name are good.

I appreciate if you help me solve this issue.

Edit: The missing quotes were typos. It is not the real problem.

Comment: You're missing a few quotes in your code (and the error).  Is that a typo?  `'NAME=>"Eray",` and `INSERT INTO People ("NAME", "SURNAME", CITY"`

Comment: yea it is typo. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error. Appostrophe missing
use

```
'NAME'=>"Eray",
```

instead  of

```
'NAME=>"Eray",
```